# Can I use Azure Even hub hostname as the backend of application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to stream logs from a VM which is acting as a server, App GW is like a prozy server to route the messages to event hub. In my configuration I've the VM's IP as the frontend IP and backend pool has the event hub host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign the VM's public IP to the Application Gateway, then your VM will not have an IP. You cannot assign same IP to 2 resources.

You can configure the Eventhub hostname as the Application gateway backend pool.